# How to locate certain html tags with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html

I want to extract information with Python and BeautifulSoup from `div class = "wxColumn wxColumn-seven dotw_0"` until  `div class = "wxColumn wxColumn-seven dotw_6"` but I don't know how to locate these divs. please help. Thanks a lot.
here are codes I wrote

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.meteomedia.com/ca/meteo/quebec/montreal")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
week = soup.find(id = "seven-day-periods")
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":'divTableBody'})
```

Answer (score 0):

that attrs is not required just do it like I did if it is a class you are looking for

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.meteomedia.com/ca/meteo/quebec/montreal")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
week = soup.find(id = "seven-day-periods")
items = soup.find_all('div', {"class":'divTableBody'})
```

if it is id just replace the class

```
items = soup.find_all('div', {"id":'divTableBody'})
```

and so on
and this `find_all` return in array so you have loop on it but there another method pick the first match which is `find`

Comment: when I print items, only divTableBody displays without its chidren "wxColumn-seven dotw_0" and so on.    please let me know how to locate the children of divTableBody

Comment: mr @NeoWong may be it doesn't have them because i try on site and i accessed the first div tag `items = soup.find_all('div', {"class": 'noMobile'})` and it worked so check other divs